# If I do a PCA on centered only variables (of the same unit), does it mean that the principal components created expresses themselves with that unit?

Tags: pca, units

This question might look very trivial, but PCA is still nebulous to me.

If I have a set of individuals described by 10 variables: $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J$, all quantitative and having the same unit (let's say: Euro),

If I choose to only center them,
and ask my PCA to find two components, and that it creates two axes:

- $PC_1$ summarizing $A, B$, for example,
- $PC_2$ summarizing $E, F, J$

does it mean that $PC_1$ unit is euro/euro
and $PC_2$ is euro/euro/euro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Principle components are linear combinations of the original variables. The first one has the largest variance, the next has the second largest, and so on, subject to a fixed constraint on each set of coefficients.

If all the variables are measured on the same scale then the resulting linear combinations have that scale also.

If we were to do a PCA on the size measurements of mammals, say length, width, and height, all measured on the single scale of centimeters, then the resulting components are also centimeters. If we add another scale, say weight in kilograms, then the components are a mix of different measuring systems and we can't assign a standard measure to, for example, the first component. All we can do is call it "size."

Most people don't care since there measurements might be on several different scales.

Comment: Thanks! I have also to figure that having a principle component in the same unit than the original variables doesn't mean that the value of this principle component has a meaning: if I'm 1m80 tall, have a bike of 1.10m height and a chair of $0.9m$ height, a $PC_1$ could be $1.32m$, but if someone ask me: "_1.32m is height of what?_", I will be in trouble to respond. It's a new variable, having an unit of measure... But measuring nothing [I mean: nothing you can easily and clearly explain to someone].